# LinkedList data structure, why we need to call empty default constructor from a different constructor

Tags: java, data-structures, constructor, linked-list, default-constructor

In `java.util.LinkedList` class, there are 2 constructors defined, default and parameterized that accepts a collection. When I looked at the implementation, I see that the parameterized constructor has `this()`, basically is calling the default constructor.

But the default constructor is empty. So I was just curious if this is a best practice to call default constructor even if its empty or is there any reasoning behind this. What happens if we don't call default constructor.

[GrepCode LinkedList implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#118)

Answer (score 2):

If the default constructor is extended at any time in the future, the other constructor does not have to be changed.

It tells us, that the extended constructor is **basically a default constructor**, but with some added special functionality (for convenience).

Answer (score 2):

It simply means any form on initialization of `LinkedList` must perform default initialization steps first.

It might seem weird to you as there are no default initialization steps as of now (but might come up later).

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a recognized good practice. Maybe the default constructor did something in previous versions. Maybe the developer thought it would be a good idea, so that if something additional is done in the default constructor, it will also be done in the other one. If you look at ArrayList, you'll see that a different choice was made.

> What happens if we don't call default constructor.

The default constructor is just not called. The superclass no-arg constructor is called implicitely.

Answer (score 1):

The parametrized version should create a list the same way as not parametrized, and call a method to add elements additionally. The fact that default constructor is empty is implementation specific.

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list.
 */
public LinkedList() {
}
```

The fact that it's intended to construct it this way remains.

Comment: +1. You're probably right: the developer's intention is probably to make it clear that creating a List from a Collection first consists in creating an empty list, then in adding all the elements of the given collection.